# 3G/4G not working but WIFI does, Android studio

Tags: java, android

I have an application that uses Internet to download a picture and then show it.
When I'm using WIFI everything works perfectly. 
When I use my cellular data (4G or LTE) I have the following error:

```
02-22 21:38:08.532  14183-14739/castiel.changes W/System.err﹕java.net.SocketTimeoutException
02-22 21:38:08.541  14183-14739/castiel.changes W/System.err﹕ at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:488)
02-22 21:38:08.541  14183-14739/castiel.changes W/System.err﹕ at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$000(PlainSocketImpl.java:37)
02-22 21:38:08.541  14183-14739/castiel.changes W/System.err﹕ at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketInputStream.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:237)
02-22 21:38:08.541  14183-14739/castiel.changes W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okio.Okio$2.read(Okio.java:113)
02-22 21:38:08.542  14183-14739/castiel.changes W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okio.RealBufferedSource.indexOf(RealBufferedSource.java:147)
02-22 21:38:08.542  14183-14739/castiel.changes W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.java:94)
02-22 21:38:08.542  14183-14739/castiel.changes W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection$ChunkedSource.readChunkSize(HttpConnection.java:514)
02-22 21:38:08.542  14183-14739/castiel.changes W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection$ChunkedSource.read(HttpConnection.java:495)
02-22 21:38:08.542  14183-14739/castiel.changes W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okio.RealBufferedSource$1.read(RealBufferedSource.java:168)
02-22 21:38:08.542  14183-14739/castiel.changes W/System.err﹕ at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:162)
02-22 21:38:08.542  14183-14739/castiel.changes W/System.err﹕ at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.fill(InflaterInputStream.java:194)
02-22 21:38:08.543  14183-14739/castiel.changes W/System.err﹕ at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:153)
02-22 21:38:08.543  14183-14739/castiel.changes W/System.err﹕ at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.read(GZIPInputStream.java:140)
02-22 21:38:08.543  14183-14739/castiel.changes W/System.err﹕ at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:290)
02-22 21:38:08.543  14183-14739/castiel.changes W/System.err﹕ at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:162)
02-22 21:38:08.543  14183-14739/castiel.changes W/System.err﹕ at org.jsoup.helper.DataUtil.readToByteBuffer(DataUtil.java:154)
02-22 21:38:08.543  14183-14739/castiel.changes W/System.err﹕ at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:567)
02-22 21:38:08.543  14183-14739/castiel.changes W/System.err﹕ at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:493)
02-22 21:38:08.544  14183-14739/castiel.changes W/System.err﹕ at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:205)
02-22 21:38:08.544  14183-14739/castiel.changes W/System.err﹕ at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:194)
02-22 21:38:08.544  14183-14739/castiel.changes W/System.err﹕ at castiel.changes.BlackMarket$Download.getImageUrl(BlackMarket.java:97)
02-22 21:38:08.544  14183-14739/castiel.changes W/System.err﹕ at castiel.changes.BlackMarket$Download.downloadImage(BlackMarket.java:110)
02-22 21:38:08.544  14183-14739/castiel.changes W/System.err﹕ at castiel.changes.BlackMarket$Download.doInBackground(BlackMarket.java:83)
02-22 21:38:08.544  14183-14739/castiel.changes W/System.err﹕ at castiel.changes.BlackMarket$Download.doInBackground(BlackMarket.java:78)
02-22 21:38:08.544  14183-14739/castiel.changes W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
02-22 21:38:08.544  14183-14739/castiel.changes W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
02-22 21:38:08.545  14183-14739/castiel.changes W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
02-22 21:38:08.545  14183-14739/castiel.changes W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
02-22 21:38:08.545  14183-14739/castiel.changes W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
02-22 21:38:08.545  14183-14739/castiel.changes W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
02-22 21:38:08.545  14183-14739/castiel.changes W/System.err﹕ java.net.MalformedURLException
02-22 21:38:08.548  14183-14739/castiel.changes W/System.err﹕ at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:152)
02-22 21:38:08.548  14183-14739/castiel.changes W/System.err﹕ at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:125)
02-22 21:38:08.548  14183-14739/castiel.changes W/System.err﹕ at castiel.changes.BlackMarket$Download.downloadImage(BlackMarket.java:111)
02-22 21:38:08.548  14183-14739/castiel.changes W/System.err﹕ at castiel.changes.BlackMarket$Download.doInBackground(BlackMarket.java:83)
02-22 21:38:08.549  14183-14739/castiel.changes W/System.err﹕ at castiel.changes.BlackMarket$Download.doInBackground(BlackMarket.java:78)
02-22 21:38:08.549  14183-14739/castiel.changes W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
02-22 21:38:08.550  14183-14739/castiel.changes W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
02-22 21:38:08.555  14183-14739/castiel.changes W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
02-22 21:38:08.555  14183-14739/castiel.changes W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
02-22 21:38:08.555  14183-14739/castiel.changes W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
02-22 21:38:08.555  14183-14739/castiel.changes W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
02-22 21:44:58.942  14183-14183/castiel.changes I/Timeline﹕ Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@3d16c587 time:687507851
02-22 21:45:01.395  14183-14183/castiel.changes I/Timeline﹕ Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@3eec504a time:687510304
02-22 21:45:02.337  14183-14183/castiel.changes I/Timeline﹕ Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:castiel.changes time:687511245
02-22 21:45:02.503  14183-14183/castiel.changes I/Timeline﹕ Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@3c621602 time:687511412
02-22 21:45:05.787  14183-16350/castiel.changes W/System.err﹕ java.net.SocketTimeoutException
02-22 21:45:05.789  14183-16350/castiel.changes W/System.err﹕ at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:488)
02-22 21:45:05.789  14183-16350/castiel.changes W/System.err﹕ at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$000(PlainSocketImpl.java:37)
02-22 21:45:05.795  14183-16350/castiel.changes W/System.err﹕ at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketInputStream.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:237)
02-22 21:45:05.795  14183-16350/castiel.changes W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okio.Okio$2.read(Okio.java:113)
02-22 21:45:05.795  14183-16350/castiel.changes W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okio.RealBufferedSource.indexOf(RealBufferedSource.java:147)
02-22 21:45:05.796  14183-16350/castiel.changes W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.java:94)
02-22 21:45:05.796  14183-16350/castiel.changes W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection$ChunkedSource.readChunkSize(HttpConnection.java:514)
02-22 21:45:05.798  14183-16350/castiel.changes W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection$ChunkedSource.read(HttpConnection.java:495)
02-22 21:45:05.799  14183-16350/castiel.changes W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okio.RealBufferedSource$1.read(RealBufferedSource.java:168)
02-22 21:45:05.799  14183-16350/castiel.changes W/System.err﹕ at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:162)
02-22 21:45:05.799  14183-16350/castiel.changes W/System.err﹕ at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.fill(InflaterInputStream.java:194)
02-22 21:45:05.799  14183-16350/castiel.changes W/System.err﹕ at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:153)
02-22 21:45:05.802  14183-16350/castiel.changes W/System.err﹕ at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.read(GZIPInputStream.java:140)
02-22 21:45:05.802  14183-16350/castiel.changes W/System.err﹕ at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:290)
02-22 21:45:05.802  14183-16350/castiel.changes W/System.err﹕ at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:162)
02-22 21:45:05.802  14183-16350/castiel.changes W/System.err﹕ at org.jsoup.helper.DataUtil.readToByteBuffer(DataUtil.java:154)
02-22 21:45:05.802  14183-16350/castiel.changes W/System.err﹕ at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:567)
02-22 21:45:05.802  14183-16350/castiel.changes W/System.err﹕ at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:493)
02-22 21:45:05.802  14183-16350/castiel.changes W/System.err﹕ at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:205)
02-22 21:45:05.802  14183-16350/castiel.changes W/System.err﹕ at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:194)
02-22 21:45:05.803  14183-16350/castiel.changes W/System.err﹕ at castiel.changes.BlackMarket$Download.getImageUrl(BlackMarket.java:97)
02-22 21:45:05.803  14183-16350/castiel.changes W/System.err﹕ at castiel.changes.BlackMarket$Download.downloadImage(BlackMarket.java:110)
02-22 21:45:05.803  14183-16350/castiel.changes W/System.err﹕ at castiel.changes.BlackMarket$Download.doInBackground(BlackMarket.java:83)
```

and lines and lines and again lines haha.

Here is my code :

```
public class BlackMarket extends ActionBarActivity {
ImageView BlackImage ;
TextView prez ;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_black_market);
        BlackImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageBlack);
        prez = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.prez);
        new Download().execute();


}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_black_market, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


private class Download extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    private String updateDate = "Mise à jour du: ";
    private Bitmap bitmap = null ;
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        this.downloadImage();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
        prez.setText("Les devises sont à l'unité et le prix de vente et d'achat sont en DA.\nExemple:\n euro = 182,5 DA à la vente.\n\n" + this.updateDate);
        BlackImage.setImageBitmap(this.bitmap);
    }

    public String getImageUrl(String url) {
        Document document;
        String imageUrl = null;
        try {
            document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
            Elements img = document.select("img[src$= DevisesDZ%2BCurrency.png]");
            imageUrl = img.attr("src");
            this.updateDate += document.getElementsByTag("h3").get(1).getAllElements().get(1).toString().split(">", 10)[2].split("<")[0];
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return imageUrl;
    }

    public void downloadImage() {
        try {
            String imageUrl = getImageUrl("http://www.devisesdz.com");
            URL urlImage = new URL(imageUrl);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) urlImage.openConnection();
            connection.setConnectTimeout(70000);
            InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
            this.bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);

        }  catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}
```

}

So as I said, everything works perfectly with WIFI but not with cellular data ???? 
Than in advance for your help :D

Comment: Have you tried removing the timeout you have set?

Comment: Yes I initially don't use it. I just added it because I thought it will help. :)

Comment: From the looks of your stack trace it looks as if it could be something to do with... this bit     document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

Comment: Oh and also in your downloadImage method don't forget to close your inputStream :)

Comment: You have a malformed url exception.  Something in your parsing of the image name isn't working.  Or perhaps you're getting a relative URL and not remembering to translate it back to fully qualified?

Comment: If it was any problem of URL or of reading from a file, it wouldn't work with WIFI.

Comment: It works perfectly when i use WIFI, but it doesn't work when i'm using my cellular data. ?? 0.o Weird

Comment: If you are using a URL that only works within your local area network, then it should only work with WiFi, but not cellular. That or your cell provider is blocking the connection for some reason

Comment: I think it's mostly related to the speed of the cellular network because sometimes when i have a high 4G it works.

Comment: Maybe i can avoid this, when using cellular --> Alert ( it would be better to use wifi) but I don't know how to detect if it is WIFI or not ??

Answer (score 0):

you want to add user permission to your Manifest.xml for enable the GPRS/3G/4G network in you android phone

Comment: What do you mean? `android.permission.INTERNET` is the permission for *all* internet, no?

Comment: Maybe I can try ?? how can I do it ??